# get the meta data from an advert iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, meta

I want to put advertising in my site in a similar way as Google Display. I'm using iframe to insert the ads but I'm having problems with the size of it.

I don't know why the iframe are sized by default in 300 x 150 no matter the source size.

The adverts have a meta line with the size of it.

```
<meta name="ad.size" content="width=300,height=250">
```

I want to take this information and change the iframe size with javascript. I tryed:

```
$('#myiframe').load(function() {
        var element = document.querySelector('meta[name="ad.size"]')['content‌​'];
});
```

and the result is empty.

Please your help.

B/R

Answer (score -1):

ok, I finally got it:

```
var adif= document.getElementById('myiframe');
var x= adif.contentWindow.document.getElementsByName("ad.size")[0].content;
```

I hope it helps someone else.